# Display solr result by specific field order

Tags: search

I am implemented the Apache Solr with Search API module.
Everything working fine but now requirement is to show solr result by specific field order.

I have total 4 fields in content type

1. Field 1
2. Field 2
3. Field 3
4. Field 4

Now solr show result random order from this field i.e any field coming on top.

**I need to show result by field order.
 i.e display all result on top by matching "field 1" then "field 2" and so on.. Anyone can help me to achieve this result...**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am resolve my problem by using edismax of solr.

Ref Link: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+DisMax+Query+Parser

http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/select?q=search_word&wt=json&indent=true
**&defType=edismax&qf=field_1^20+field_2^19+field_3^18+field_4^17&pf=field_1+field_2+field_3+field_4**